# Finding minimum of $f(x)=3^{x^2-4x}$ without calculus

Tags: inequality

> Find the minimum value of the function $f(x)=3^{x^2-4x}$ without using calculus.

I know how to do it by using calculus but I was wondering if this can be achieved by using the am-gm inequality by taking the natural log on both sides so $\ln(f(x))=(x^2-4x)\ln(3)$ ?

Comment: The minimum occurs when $x^2-4x$ is a minimum. So you just have to find the minimum of a quadratic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, let's just consider the function $f(x) = 3^x$ for a moment. It's clear that for every $x<y$ that $3^x<3^y$ ie the smaller $x$ is, the smaller $3^x$ is. So, to minimize the function you gave us, you would have to find when $x^2-4x$ has it's minimum. We can do that in the following way: If the quadratic is $ax^2 + bx + c$, the minimum is at $-b/2a$, so the minimum of $x^2-4x$ is at $x = 2$. Plugging $x = 2$ into $x^2 - 4x$, we find that the minimum of $x^2-4x$ is $-4$. Therefore, the minimum to your equation is $3^{-4}$. I hope that this helps!

Comment: How do we get that the minimum is at -b/(2a) without using calculus?

Comment: @Hugh I honestly have no idea. I'm assuming that this is someone who hasn't been taught calculus, but has been taught that formula.

Comment: $x^2-4x=(x-2)^2-4$ could be easier to see the minimum.

Answer (score 4):

$$\;\;f(x) = 3^{x^2-4x} = 3^{(x^2-4x+4)-4} = \frac{1}{3^4} \cdot 3^{(x-2)^2} \ge \frac{1}{3^4} \cdot 3^0  = \frac{1}{3^4}$$

Comment: Why inequality is this?

Comment: @dydxx Because $u = (x-2)^2 \ge 0$ and $u \mapsto 3^u$ is an increasing function.

Answer (score 1):

$e^{\mbox{crud}}$ will be smallest when crud is smallest.  Here, crud $=x^2-4x$, whose graph is a parabola.  It will be smallest at its vertex.  One way to find the vertex is to note that $x^2-4x$ crosses the $x$-axis at $x=0$ and $x=4$, which means the $x$-coordinate of the vertex is at $x=2$.  This makes the minimum $3^{-4}={1\over 81}$.

Answer (score 1):

The function $y\mapsto 3^y$ is a strictly increasing function, hence $3^{x^2-4x}$ attains its minimum when $x^2-4x$ is at its minimum. The problem is then reduced to finding the minimum of $x^2-4x$.